# populating array without calloc and malloc in c?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, allocation

I have code that looks like

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
char ***matrix;
matrix = calloc(2, sizeof(char **));
for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
    matrix[i] = calloc(ROWS+2, sizeof(char*));
    for (int j=0; j<COLS; j++){
        matrix[i][j] = malloc(COLS+2);
        memset(matrix[i][j], (int)DEFAULT, COLS+2);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do a similar kind of thing without the use of malloc and calloc? For example, in the case of 1d array I know you can do something like this

```
unsigned char malloc_data[MAX_SIZE];
size_t malloc_used;  /* automatically initialized to zero */

void *stack_malloc(size_t size) {
void *p = &malloc_data[malloc_used];
if(size + malloc_used > MAX_SIZE) return 0;  /* out of memory */
malloc_used += size;
return p;
}
```

OR something like this

```
static char *allocp = allocbuf[0];
if (allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - allocp >= n) { /* it fits */
```

and

```
if (p >= allocbuf && p < allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE)
```

I want to try to use stack variables and temps instead of dynamic memory allocated ways. However, when I try to think about how to apply these types of ways to my three dimensional sense, my head starts spinning. Please help clarify things to me

Comment: Is `char ***matrix;` really necessary?

Comment: Why do you think `malloc_used` is automatically initialised to zero when there is no ` = 0` to make it so?

Comment: @ChrisTurner variables with static storage duration automatically are.

Comment: @randomvalue Why can't you use your first code but with stack_malloc? Are you confused about how to write stack_calloc?

Comment: Note that your first code does not create a three-dimensional array. It creates an array of pointers to arrays of pointers to arrays.

Comment: @usera253751 it says three dimensional sense, no where does it say array

Comment: @ChrisTurner I believe the size_t data type might have something to do with it but Idk

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to keep the triple pointer usage, the storage can be allocated on the stack and initialized like this:

```
char ***matrix;
char **mats_[2];
char *mat_rows_[2][ROWS+2];
char mat_cols_[2][ROWS+2][COLS+2];
matrix = &mats_[0];
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    matrix[i] = &mat_rows_[i][0];
    for (int j = 0; j < ROWS+2; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = &mat_cols_[i][j][0];
        memset(matrix[i][j], (int)DEFAULT, COLS+2);
    }
}
```

You could also define `matrix` as an array[2] of `char **` instead of a single `char ***`, which would allow you to eliminate the `mats_` variable:

```
char **matrix[2];
char *mat_rows_[2][ROWS+2];
char mat_cols_[2][ROWS+2][COLS+2];
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    ...
```

---

In the comments below, OP asked whether the `memset` was necessary. All the elements of `mat_cols_[2][ROWS+2][COLS+2]` need to be set to the same value `DEFAULT`. If `DEFAULT` can be replaced with `0`, this is easy to do by defining `mat_cols_` with an initializer with pretty much everything defaulting to 0:

```
char mat_cols_[2][ROWS+2][COLS+2] = { 0 };
```

If `DEFAULT` cannot be replaced with 0, the only way to do it would be for the initializer to supply values for all the elements explicitly, which has a maintainability problem since the dimensions are defined in terms of the macros `ROWS` and `COLS`. The GNU C Compiler (GCC) has an extension to the C language designated initializers that allows a range of array elements to be initialized to the same value.  That could be used as follows:

```
char mat_cols_[2][ROWS+2][COLS+2] =
    {[0 ... 1] =
        {[0 ... ROWS+2-1] =
            {[0 ... COLS+2-1] = DEFAULT}
        }
    };
```

Comment: is memset necessary or could you use variables?

Comment: @randomvalue If `DEFAULT` is 0, you could declare `mat_cols_` with an initializer: `char mat_cols_[2][ROWS+2][COLS+2] = {0};`. Otherwise the initializer would need to initialize all 2*(ROWS+2)*(COLS+2) elements of `mat_cols_[2][ROWS+2][COLS+2]` explicitly.

Comment: would you please update the ... of your second code and maybe add without memset? I tried using char ** instead of a single char *** but am getting assignment from incompatible pointer type error

Comment: @randomvalue However, there is a GCC extension for initializing a range of array elements to the same value: `char mat_cols[2][ROWS+2][COLS+2] = {[0...1] = {[0...ROWS+2-1] = {[0...COLS+2-1] = DEFAULT}}};`.

Comment: DEFAULT is not zero. It's value was meant to be insignificant like DEFAULT = 80.

Comment: the char mat_cols_[2][ROWS+2][COLS+2] = { 0 }; works but the char mat_cols_[2][ROWS+2][COLS+2] =
    {[0 ... 1] =
        {[0 ... ROWS+2-1] =
            {[0 ... COLS+2-1] = DEFAULT}
        }
    }; way I was getting error- "expected expression before '{' token { [0 ... 1] =  " not sure why